# How to get a button sender id? in SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui, ibaction

```
                    Button(button1Name, action: messageMe)
                .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: 300)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .tag("button1")
            
             }
         }
    }
}

func messageMe(//get sender) {
    print("Button Tag " //sender.id)
}
```

How can I get the tag of the button sent, so that I can run an action depending on which button was pressed? I know this is very basic, but cannot find a solution for SwiftUI. I'm back to developing after around 4 years and my beloved Objective-C is no more!

Comment: passing a paramater to your function (messageMe) can solve this problem

Comment: Objective-C is still there - you can use it in full range with all iOS frameworks, but if you want to use swift+SwiftUI then you need to learn new concepts and in swift language and in SwiftUI framework.

Comment: @Asperi would you recommend I take on Swift+SwiftUI or go back to my (preferred) Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly , without any needs of `tag` like that :

```
Button("Button title 1") {
  print("Button tapped!")
  messageMe(buttonId :"1")
}
.frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: 300)
.padding()
.foregroundColor(.white)
.background(Color.gray)
.cornerRadius(20)

func messageMe(buttonId : String) {
  // use the buttonId
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!